# Site is looking for resources on server root instead of site root

Tags: resources, structure, umbraco

I have recently built a website using Umbraco with Visual Studio, and have subsequently moved this to my IIS server. The structure is as so:

```
 -Root      
    -Sites
        -ApplicationHost                    
              -UmbracoSite
```

My problem is that when the site looks for the Media folder (and some other folders), it is referenced from the root directory. I've read some articles about changing the web config and the umbraco config, but neither has worked.

I've worked around the problem by creating a few virtual directories from root, but this is less than ideal!

Can anyone help an Umbracoer in need???

Cheers

Rich

Comment: Don't really understand the structure of your site. For example, what should the url of the media folder be?

Comment: Hi! 
The media folder is under the UmbracoSite level, but the umbraco framework is looking for the media folder under the ApplicationHost(root) level.

Comment: So are you hosting the umbraco site in a virtual directory under another site?

Comment: No it's an application under a site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to set ResolveUrlsFromTextString = true in umbracoSettings.config for Umbraco to work with the virtual directory.

Comment: Cheers for the reply James, however; I've already set that to true.